# Get value of textbox on ng-keypress in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get the value of the textbox on keypress.

I have html code like

```
<input style="width: 20%; float: right;" 
       ng-model="que.SelectedOptionsUID" 
       type="text" 
       ng-keypress="myFunct($event)"/>
```

And JS code on my controller:

```
$scope.myFunct = function (e) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    //i want here value of the textbox 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<input style="width: 20%; float: right;" 
       ng-model="que.SelectedOptionsUID" 
       type="text" 
       ng-keypress="myFunct($event, que.SelectedOptionsUID)"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.myFunct = function (e, myValue) {
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;        
    // do something with myValue
}
```

Comment: the values comes after next item say one would type "a" it will come null and then type "ab" it will come "a"